# National Character affecting its Jewish Community

Tags: sources-mekorot, gentiles, chutz-laaretz, am-yisrael-jewish-nation, yekke

In pg. 3 of [this interview](http://www.kayj.net/mm/memoirs/Chevroni,%20The%20Unacknowledged%20Heritage.pdf) by R' Hamburger שליט“א, he asserts in the name of  the Michtav miEliyohu (Dessler זצ”ל) that the character of each nation's non-Jewish majority affected the temperment and expression of its Jewish inhabitants.

What is the source of this in Michtav miEliyohu and what (if anything) is his source for this assertion?

Answer (score 3):

Rabbi Hamburger quotes the source as:

> Michtav
>   Mei'Eliyahu, vol. IV, Yerushalayim 5745, pp. 129-30

He also goes on to quote Reb Yehuda HaChassid:

> Sefer Chassidim (siman #1101), `In most places, the conduct of the
>   Jews reflects that of the local gentiles. If, for example, the gentiles behave morally, the Jewish
>   youth born in that city will be the same.' This might explain the phenomenon of the second [and
>   Israeli-born] generation of the German immigrants, who are not terribly similar to their forbears etc.

Rabbi Hamburger seems to link these two ideas.
Very interesting article. Thank you.